# Searching two lists with nested loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to find an apartment number which is not already taken. So `list<>` is a list with already taken apartments and `all<>` is a list of all the apartments. so I try to iterate through them to find an apartment that is not already taken.

This does not work:

```
list<> // 4 indexes
all<> // 25 indexes

for (int i = 0;i < all.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {   
        if (all[i].apartmentNr != list[j].apartmentNr)
        {
            apartmentNr = all[i].apartmentNr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't check all the `list` items so `apartmentNr` is set on first mismatch, but it's possibly taken on next list item. Thus you need to check all `list` items, before you can make a conclusion that it's free:

```
list<> // 4 indexes
all<> // 25 indexes

for (int i = 0;i < all.Count; i++)
{
    bool taken = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {   
        if (all[i].apartmentNr == list[j].apartmentNr)
        {
            taken = true;
            break; // no need to check the rest
        }
    }
    if (!taken) {
        apartmentNr = all[i].apartmentNr;
        break; // found first free
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

//availableApartments will contain all available apartments
var availableApartments = all.Except(list) 

// Will get you the first item.
var freeApartment = availableApartments.FirstOrDefault()
```

Reference - [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)